# Match first few letters of a file name : Shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to match first few letters of a file.

```
for entry in `ls`; do
    echo $entry
done
```

With the above code I get the name of all the files.

I have a few files with similar name at the start:

```
Beaglebone-v1
Beaglebone-v3
Beaglebone-v2
```

How can I compare `$entry` with Beaglebone* and then extract the latest version file name?

Comment: Warning for all contenders: For single digits you can do `list=Beaglebone-v*; echo ${list##Beaglebone-}`.  For larger numbers you need to sort numerically, which requires a little more work.

Comment: @Henk good point. I've taken care of it in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to loop over all `Beaglebone-*` files:

```
for entry in Beaglebone-* ; do
    echo $entry
done
```

if you just need the file with the latest version, you can depend on the fact that ls sorts your names alphabetically, so you could just do:

```
LATEST_FILE_NAME=$(ls Beaglebone-* | tail -n 1)
```

which will just take the last one alphabetically.

Comment: There's absolutely no need to use `ls` there, in fact [parsing `ls` is discouraged](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: yes indeed, thanks for the remark. I changed it in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

To deal with larger numbers, you could use numeric comparison like this:

```
stem="Beaglebone-v"
for file in $stem*; do 
    ver=${file#"$stem"}          # cut away stem to get version number        
    (( ver > max )) && max=$ver  # conditionally assign `ver` to `max` 
done
echo "$stem$max"
```

Testing it out:

```
bash-4.3$ ls Beaglebone-v*
Beaglebone-v1  Beaglebone-v10  Beaglebone-v2  Beaglebone-v3
bash-4.3$ stem="Beaglebone-v" &&
for file in $stem*
  do
    ver=${file#"$stem"}
    (( ver > max )) && max=$ver
  done; echo "$stem$max"
Beaglebone-v10
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the filenames matching the pattern in an array and then pick the last element of the array.

```
shopt -s nullglob
arr=( Beaglebone-* )
if (( ${#arr[@]} > 0 ))
then
    latest="${arr[ (( ${#arr[@]} - 1 )) ]}"
    echo "$latest"
fi
```

You need to enable `nullglob` so that if there are no files matching the pattern, you will get an empty array rather than the pattern itself.

Answer (score 0):

If version numbers can go beyond single digits,

```
function version_numbers {
    typeset w; for w in $1-v*; do echo ${w#$1-v}; done
}

version_numbers "Beaglebone" | sort -n | tail -1
```

Or, adding function `max`:

```
# read a stream of numbers, from stdin (one per line)
# and return the largest value
function max
{
  typeset _max n
  read _max || return
  while read n; do
    ((_max < n)) && _max=$n
  done
  echo $_max
}
```

We can now do the whole thing without external commands:

```
version_numbers Beaglebone | max
```

Note that `max` will fail horribly if any one line fails the numerical comparison.